# java -version showing different version than in path

Tags: java, java-8

I have `jdk12` and `jdk8` on my computer installed. Usually `jdk12` is set in the path.
To run some java programs I had set path to `jdk8`. Now after changing the path back to `/jdk-12.0.1/bin`, running java -version on cmd still returns

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You probably have both JDK 8 and JDK 12 paths added to paths, either directly or via a variable. Be careful that Oracle also exports the path when installing Java.

Comment: Have you closed and reopened the cmd window?

Comment: When calling `java` on the command line, the OS only uses the `PATH` environment variable to look for the command. The variable `JAVA_HOME` is not used here. So you simply should examine the `PATH` variable

Comment: @SilviuBurcea So when i write ```where java``` on cmd it gives ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\java.exe```

Comment: The directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` is added to the `PATH` by the JDK installer. I would suggest to remove it, so you have better control what directories are there.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks, hadn't noticed the path under system variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to assemble my comments to an answer:

When calling `java` on the command line, the OS only uses the `PATH` environment variable to look for the command. The variable `JAVA_HOME` is not used here.

So you simply should examine the `PATH` variable: The directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` is added to the `PATH` by the JDK installer. I would suggest to remove it, so you have better control what directories are part of the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple Java installed, create the `JAVA_HOME` variable and give the JAVA path which you want to use. Use only this `JAVA_HOME` variable in the `PATH` variable.

If you wish to change the default Java, change only the `JAVA_HOME` variable pointing to the required JAVA.

This way, only one JAVA (which is required) will be present in `PATH`. Remove all other JAVA references in the `PATH` variable.

Also, whenever you change the `JAVA_HOME` value, open a new terminal (command prompt) to verify this change.

Note: If the path contains spaces, use the shortened path name. `For example, C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`